# export to csv the value of only one cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, icalendar

I'm working with a dataframe that has basically 2 columns.

In the 1st column, each cell contains a string that is the body of a ics (iCalendar) file similar to this one:

```
df['body'][0]

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar_blablabla
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20210421T150000Z
DTEND:20210421T163000Z
DESCRIPTION:Webinar
LOCATION:Webinar
SUMMARY:Webinar
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In the 2nd column, each cell contains the name of the ics file associated to the 1st column, in this case could be:

```
df['filename'][0]

this_is_the_webinar_0.ics
```

so the result is like this one:

```
    body                                                filename
0   BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:icalendar...   this_is_the_webinar_0.ics
1   BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:icalendar...   this_is_the_webinar_1.ics
2   BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:icalendar...   this_is_the_webinar_2.ics
```

So now I would like to export the content of each cell `df['body'][i]` to a txt file named as `df['filename'][i]`.

That is something like:

```
df['body'][i].to_csv(df['filename'][i]], index=False)
```

but actually I got the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'` since I'm trying to export a string instead of an entire dataframe.

Any idea about how to solve it?

any help is much appreciated
thanks in advance

g

Comment: What exactly do you want in the files?

Comment: generating ics files, having the name picked from 'filename' column and the content from 'body' column of the same row as the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify, no need to use `to_csv()`

- synthesised content using **lorem**
- just loop over **body** and **filename** writing to a text file

```
from lorem_text import lorem
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.DataFrame([{"body":lorem.paragraph(), "filename":Path.cwd().joinpath(f"name_{f}.ics")} for f in range(10)])
for body, filename in df.loc[:,["body","filename"]].values:
    with open(filename, "w") as f: f.write(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile i found another solution not involving pandas dataframe

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file_with_data.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    savedfile = open(sheet.cell(row, column=2).value, 'w') #column 2 contains the name of ics files
    savedfile.write(sheet.cell(row, column=1).value)       #column 1 contains the body of each ics file
    savedfile.close()
```